# Problem with cookie and session cache

Tags: 8, caching, cookies

I have a problem with the Drupal cache. The cache remembers session and cookie values. Everything works fine when I'm logged in or when I completely turn off any cache.

Is it possible to use cookies and avoid they are cached for anonymous users?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add the correct cache context when rendering cookie/session values. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts. Then you should no longer need to completely turn off caching and sessions should work fine, anonymous and logged in.

Using non-session cookies server-side can be a problem with reverse proxies in general and the built-in *Internal Page Cache* in specific. Disable it by triggering the kill switch on pages depending on cookies without a session:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

Don't use this trigger too often, it disables all page caching. If you need it on the majority of your pages then uninstall the *Internal Page Cache*, but keep the *Internal Dynamic Page Cache* enabled. If the dynamic page cache is too slow then put a third-party page cache in front which has the options you need to manage your cookies.